# Facebook do I need app_id to integrate open graph on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have been reading about using Open Graph (OG) meta tags to improve the way facebook works with your website. I have read two tutorials that say to create an application and use the application ID. But I am not developing an application, all I have is a business page... Can I just the page ID?

Can anybody also point out any good, simple resources around the using OG in my website?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sharer.php method (which is deprecated) allows you to post without an application.  The feed/post method appears to require an app_id, though it's possible that there's some way around that.  On the bright side, there's nothing complex about creating an application, so, if that's what you must do, I'd say just do it :)

[Here](http://sb2013boulevard.myverizonpic.com/drawImageForFB4.php?user_videos_id=97947) is an example of how it works *with an app using the feed/post method (you'll need to click the "Post to feed" link at the top (yes I know it doesn't look like a link!).

and [Here](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://sb2013boulevard.myverizonpic.com/drawImageForFB2.php?user_videos_id=97947) is the same exact example only using Sharer (notice that this time it's pointing at a slightly different url (drawImageForFB2.php instead of drawImageForFB4.php).

I use a php to render the tags based on the vidId that I collect but that's neither here nor there... you could just as easily have this as a static HTML page.

The innards of the OG tag are just about identical and the app_id tag in the OG is entirely optional as it pertains to the second example).

Oh, and addthis does it using the dialog api which looks like this

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?redirect_uri=http://s7.addthis.com/static/postshare/c00.html&app_id=140586622674265&link=http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381222-optimize-facebook-sharing#.UQ8bBJM9KQk.facebook&name=Optimize%20Facebook%20Sharing&description=